# Audio watermarking open source projects

Tags: open-source

Are you aware of any open source libraries/projects that offer audio watermarking capability?

Comment: One thing to remember is that audio watermarks won't survive compression to a format like MP3 or WMA or M4A, which is one reason they aren't used very much.

Comment: @MusiGenesis There are many commercially available watermarking solutions that claim to survive lossy compression, and even analog dubbing.

Comment: @Brad: are there any published accounts of such watermarking techniques?

Comment: @MusiGenesis http://www.musictrace.de/technologies/technologies.en.htm http://www.civolution.com/technology/digital-audio-and-video-watermarking/

Comment: @Brad: I appreciate the links, but they're only links to the claims made by these companies (which claims I assume are testable and have actually been tested). What I'm looking for is a technical description of how this watermarking is actually done, and how it could possibly survive re-encoding.

Comment: @MusiGenesis You and me both.  I'd love to find algorithms for this, which is what brought me to this thread.  It is possible... there are many companies offering these services.  I'm assuming that some form of spread spectrum watermarking is used, but I don't know much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Implementations

section 3 of this site site is on audio:  http://www.binary-universe.net/
same author did a project on codeplex.

these also do audio:
  [StegHide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net/)
  [mpeStego](http://www.petitcolas.net/fabien/steganography/mp3stego/)

Answer (score 1):

We made a [C++ watermarking library](https://github.com/jcelerier/watermarking/tree/master/src/libwatermark) as a student project.
It implements:

- Least Significant Bit watermarking (which won't resist anything),
- Spread-Spectrum Watermarking (which should resist quite a bit but is very audible),
- There is a MATLAB code for a Compression-Expansion algorithm which is said to be very robust according to the paper "Audio watermarking using time-frequency compression expansion".