# Adding text to audio for encryption

Tags: php, audio, cryptography, steganography

I am making an application in PHP that hides a string in audio file. I have seen several command line tools like SoX, AC3, ffmpeg, but they don't seem to support the functionality of adding text. Below are some links to their command line interface descriptions:

1. [AC3](http://ac3filter.net/wiki/AC3Filter_tools#noise)
2. [ffmpeg](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/command_line_media_editing)
3. [SOX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Docs/Documentation)

I am looking for a tool that allows me to hide text within the MP3 or `.wav` audio files.

Comment: Why did you tagged encryption?

Comment: I want to do encryption in the end..

Comment: That's not encryption you're talking about, it more closely resembles [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

Comment: @NullUserException I agree with you 100%...

Comment: @user1765876 The tools you listed are audio manipulation tools and thus provide no such functionality. There are software that will do what, but it's important to be more specific (eg: what format you're targeting), because for steganography to work, you need to at least partially preserve the original file, and this isn't something that can be easily generalized.

Comment: @NullUserException it is mp3 or wav..

Comment: @user1765876 See http://www.petitcolas.net/fabien/steganography/mp3stego/, http://www.jjtc.com/Steganography/tools.html

Comment: @NullUserException I read that earlier,it is fake whenever yo encode it says,datafile too long you can roughly hide 176 bits, I am just encoding hello world

Comment: @user1765876 Try a different file or different tool then.

Comment: @NullUserException I know that,that's why I posted question, Anyways Thank you for your response.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to simply put data in the headers (eg, the MP3 ID3 tags), then you are interested in audio watermarking. The wikipedia entry isn't particularly useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_watermark

This answer gives some clues:

[Audio watermarking open source projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227517/audio-watermarking-open-source-projects)

Commercial watermarking systems exist that are extremely robust, and can survive even when audio is converted between formats, D/A/D'ed, band-limited, eq'ed and so on. I'm not aware of an open source project that comes anywhere close to this, but I haven't researched it recently.

For uncompressed formats, you can use LSB stenography:

http://www.jsums.edu/cms/tues/docs/Steganography/LSB-Steganography.pdf